# Groovy and Java support matrix

Tags: java, groovy

To understand which Java / Groovy combinations will work, I'm looking for a matrix that will show this information. Both on http://www.groovy-lang.org/ and by Googling I wasn't able to find such a matrix. Does anyone have this information available? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you have any specific issue because of the compatibility? What `java & groovy` version are you looking for?

Comment: The issue is with one of our builds in Jenkins. After upgrading Jenkins, the minimum required Java version is 8 (before it was 7). The build uses Groovy 1.6. Before the build was fine, now we're on Java 8 it is failing with an error indicating that an internal class was used (by Groovy).

Comment: http://groovy-lang.org/releasenotes/groovy-2.3.html#Groovy2.3releasenotes-OfficialsupportforrunningGroovyonJDK8

Answer (score 3):

Here you have the compatibility matrix: https://groovy.apache.org/download.html#requirements

This might also be interesting for you: https://groovy-lang.org/releasenotes/groovy-2.3.html#Groovy2.3releasenotes-OfficialsupportforrunningGroovyonJDK8